# get my site_url string php wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to simply get my website url

I am using wordpress
and I am editing some PHP file
I just want to do:

```
echo '<div style="background:url('
```

and add the site url! (e.g www.something.com)
and after that add the path to my jpg file
(e.g /theams/layouts/images/somefile.jpg)

that is all I want!
but no matter what I wrote:
`URL() site_url() $SERVER`

I got error undefined

please help

Comment: Possible duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6768793/get-the-full-url-in-php

Comment: See https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/site_url, `site_url()` should work, if you do it right.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$site_url = get_site_url();

echo '<div style="background:url(\''.$site_url.'/theams/layouts/images/somefile.jpg\');"></div>';
```